# sequelize function not raising an exception in Mocha

Tags: mocha.js, sequelize.js

I am somewhat new to the mocha framework. This code should throw an exception, but doesn't. (put all code in the test for simplicity)

```
describe("Test", function() {
    it("this should throw an error", function() {
        var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
        var sequelize = new Sequelize({
            dialect: 'sqlite',
            storage: 'test.sqlite3'
        });
        var foo = sequelize.define('Foo', {
            var_a: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            var_b: Sequelize.STRING
        });
        sequelize.sync().then(function(err) {
            throw('should throw an error here); // !!! Should throw an exception here
        });
    });
});
```

Interestingly, when I run the code straight in node.js (without the "describe" and "it" lines, of course), it raises an exception like it should. I am somewhat new to mocha, is there something incredibly simple that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. From (https://mochajs.org/#getting-started): "By adding a callback (usually named "done") to it(), Mocha will know that it should wait for this function to be called to complete the test."

```
describe("Test", function() {
    it("this should throw an error", function(done) {
        var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
        var sequelize = new Sequelize({
            dialect: 'sqlite',
            storage: 'db/test_db.sqlite3'
        });
        var foo = sequelize.define('Foo', {
            var_a: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            var_b: Sequelize.STRING
        });
        sequelize.sync().then(function(err) {
            done();
            throw('got here');
        });
    });
});
```